# Python: Importing more than one workbook into python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I do not know how to import the two Excel files I was given into openpyxl.

Comment: From the online help: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file

Comment: Reading the workbook imports all of the sheets, you just have to select the one you want in your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

first_workbook = load_workbook("file_name1")
second_workbook = load_workbook("file_name2")
```

You now have two workbooks loaded into two separate variables